# Static vs Dynamic Column Generation in Angular 6 / Material

Tags: html, angular-material, angular6

Alright StackOverflow - I need your assistance.

So here we go, I am utilizing Angular 6 and Material to create a dynamic data table with checkboxes that yield the user the option to select all or individual rows.

The site, (https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview), has an example showing how this can be done. However, all the examples shown use hard-coded column IDs. I want to be able to dynamically change the column headers on the fly, thus, here's what my HTML template looks like:

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <!-- Static Checkbox Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="checkboxes">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                    [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                    [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                    [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Dynamic Column Generation -->
  <div *ngFor="let displayedColumn of displayedColumns; let columnIndex = index"> 
    <ng-container *ngIf="displayedColumn !='checkboxes'" matColumnDef="{{displayedColumn}}"> 
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>{{displayedColumn}}</th> 
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element "> {{element[displayedColumn]}}</td> 
    </ng-container> 
  </div> 

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
      (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
  </tr>

</table>
```

The supporting TypeScript is as follows:

```
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  columns = [
    { columnDef: 'uuid', header: 'UUID',   cell: (element: Module) => `${element.uuid}` },
    { columnDef: 'name', header: 'Name',   cell: (element: Module) => `${element.name}` },
    { columnDef: 'summary', header: 'Summary',   cell: (element: Module) => `${element.summary}` },
  ];

  displayedColumns = [['checkboxes'], this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)];

  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Module>(NDE_DATA_SOURCE);

  .............
```

The problem that I am having is that the console is telling me the following:
**ERROR Error: Could not find column with id "checkboxes".**

Yet, I have explicitly stated within my HTML that...

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="checkboxes">
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `displayedColumns` definition should be an array of strings, but you've made an array of arrays of string:

```
displayedColumns = [['checkboxes'], this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)];
```

Try:

```
displayedColumns = this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef);
displayedColumns.splice(0, 0, 'checkboxes');
```

Comment: What I think he was trying to achieve was es6 being: `displayedColumns = [['checkboxes'], ...this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)];` using the spread operator

Comment: Your corrected syntax would still be wrong - it would need to be `['checkboxes', ...this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)]`. Or be silly about it with `[...['checkboxes'], ...this.columns.map(c => c.columnDef)]`.

Comment: ahh yeah sorry, meant your first suggestion there. I'm currently using that in my project.